# Transform .crt and .pem files to keystore

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore

I received a .crt file and a .pem file from my registrar but I need to transform it into a keystore(JKS) to be able to use it on my server.

How do I transform the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not transform the `.crt` or `.pem` files to a `KeyStore`, you have to add them to a KeyStore.

You can add them using `keytool` by running this command:

```
keytool -importcert -keystore <KEYSTORE.JKS> -storepass <KEYSTORE_PASSWORD> -file <YOUR_CERT_OR_PEM_FILE> -alias <ALIAS_NAME>
```

This will create a KeyStore if it doesn't exist at that location and then add the certificate into it or if the KeyStore exists, it just adds the certificate to it.

You can then view if the certificate is actually added by running this command:

```
keytool -list -keystore <YOUR_KEYSTORE> -storepass <KEYSTORE_PASSWORD> -alias <ALIAS_NAME> -v
```